# What would have been a more efficient way to do this?

Tags: java

```
public class calendar
{
    public static void printMonth(int numDays, int startDays)
    {
        System.out.println("Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa");

        for(int j=0; startDays >= j; j++)
        {
            if (j==0)
                System.out.print(" ");
            else
                System.out.print("    ");               
        }
        for (int i=1; numDays >= i; i++)
        {
            if (i<=7-startDays)
                System.out.print(i + "   ");    
            else if (i<10)
                System.out.print(" " + i + "  ");
            else
                System.out.print(i + "  ");
            if ((i == 7-startDays) || (i % 7+(startDays-7) == 0))           
                System.out.print("\n");                 
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        printMonth(28,5);
    }
}
```

I wrote this in java to print out a 2d calendar thing, and I can tell it's shoddy and am curious to more efficient alternatives.

Comment: Suggestion for readability: use `j <= startDays` and `i <= numDays` for readability. I don't think I've *ever* seen the comparison reversed like this in a `for` loop.

Comment: There is a bug in it: printMonth(28, 0); doesn't work as expected!

Comment: Since you aks for a "more efficient" way, please tell us why you think this is inefficient.

Comment: Ohhh, @isnot2bad, you're right. Let me try to fix that.

And Tichodroma, I just figured that it was inefficient because I'm new to programming and I felt like this seemed really forced.

Comment: I don't think there's anything particularly slow about that code. There's a number of string-related micro-optimisations that could be made, but I would guess that the internal `System.out` routines would be the slowest portion.

Comment: The program does what it should do and it is not very inefficient. Nice exercise. By the way, you should fix the condition for printing new line when the startDays is 0 "if ((i + startDays) % 7 == 0)" is simpler and should do.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to do here. If you explain more about your requirement we can help you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a short, in my opinion more readable form (that ignores trailing spaces for the sake of readability):

```
public static void printMonth(int numDays, int startDay) {
    System.out.println("So  Mo  Di  Mi  Do  Fr  Sa");

    int column = 0;
    for(int day = 1 - startDay; day <= numDays; day++) {
        System.out.print(day > 0 ? String.format("%2d  ", day) : "    ");
        if (++column % 7 == 0) System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```